# About "navigator.mediaCapabilities.decodingInfo" question

Tags: javascript

On MDN example

```
navigator.mediaCapabilities.decodingInfo({
    type : 'file',
    audio : {
        contentType : "audio/mp3",
        channels : 2,
        bitrate : 132700,
        samplerate : 5200
    }
})
```

What is the maximum value in「bitrate」 and 「samplerate」?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Both properties are defined](https://w3c.github.io/media-capabilities/#audioconfiguration) as [`unsigned long long`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-unsigned-long-long) and [`unsigned long`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-unsigned-long) respectively, so they can be in the range `[0, 18446744073709551615]` and `[0, 4294967295]`.